# run script to open another script file

Tags: javascript

I have been tasked to add a script file to a page when you click a button. Thought this would be easy. The script displays a popup a user can fill in a form.

I have my button click working and it adds the script file to the page and calls the script file I want calling.

```
 function loadPopUp() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "/js/patpopup.js";
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        body.appendChild(script);
        console.log("clicked");
        return false;
    }
```

In the script I was given it is just a url `//r1.dotmailer-surveys.com/scripts/popover/111111?a=uc` that was wrapped in script tags. 
I can't get the popup to open it only takes me to the page where all the script is.

If I wrap it in script tags and place it in the page it opens ok.

What should I put in the `patpopup.js` file that the `script url` is in, I have tried using `window.location` and various other methods to try and get the page to open in the page and produce the popup but always opens the script instead of running it.
At the minute I only have the `url //r1.dotmailer-surveys.com/scripts/popover/111111?a=uc` in my patpopup.js file

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789521/how-to-link-external-javascript-file-onclick-of-button

Comment: Why are you adding it on button click instead of simply adding to the page and using the button click to run the functions within the script?

Comment: When it is just added to the page it just opens as soon as the page opens. I wanted to be able for the user to request it by clicking on a button then it should appear

Comment: @StudentRik Then why don't you execute that script on button click instead of dom ready.

Comment: How would I do that? if it is just a url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the protocol to make it a proper URL in this case.

I would also add it to the head instead of body unless the script document.writes stuff :

```
function loadPopUp() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = location.protocol+'//r1.dotmailer-surveys.com/scripts/popover/111111‌​?a=uc';
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(script);
    console.log("clicked");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is adding the correct script to the page now. But does not show the popup it adds an `iframe` but doesn't fire the popup opening.

Comment: I cannot tell you without seeing the script it creates

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will get onto dotmailer.