# Execute javascript scripts after onclick and getvalue

Tags: javascript

I wanted to modify something in my code and don't really know how to make this work... my code is kinda huge so I am going to explain what I want with an exemple :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/application.css">


    </head>

    <body>
      <label>Enter value : </label><input type="text" maxlength="512" id="reg_expr"/>
      <div id="button">OK</div>
        <div id="nfa"></div>

        <script src="script1.js"></script>
        <script src="script2.js"></script>
        <script src="script3.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

So this is my HTML code, so what I want to do is NOT execute these 3 scripts until the user enters a value in the text input and clicks on OK. That value will be used in the js files, so i have to get the value after I click OK.

Can someone explain how this has to work ?

EDIT : problem was with jQuery that was not executing on Electron, solution : http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7789831/6695924

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link external javascript file onclick of button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789521/how-to-link-external-javascript-file-onclick-of-button)

Answer (score 2):

For starters I would suggest changing; `<div id="button">OK</div>` to `<button id="button">OK</button>`.

I would then suggest to put each of those scripts into functions instead, then you can use the 'onClick' event from the button attribute as follows;

```
<button id="button" onClick="s1Func();s2Func();s3Func();">OK</button>
```

A better way would be to have one function call 'init' or something appropriate that then calls the 3 scripts/functions and have your buttons onClick even call that one initialization function.

JSFiddle Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/h7htk9Lp/

Comment: Could you explain the difference between using **div** and **button** for this task?

Comment: @Alexey For web development as with all languages there are some standards that aren't strictly enforced, but make more sense/are more appropriate in certain use cases. The idea is to use the closest element to what you want, so if you want a button, use a button element. In terms of clickable elements in general, the `<button>` or `<a>` elements are those that should be chosen, rather than having a `<div>` or `<span>` styled and have javascript attached to act as a button or anchor.

Comment: Maybe. But are there any benefits of using **div**? Google's main page doesn't has **button** elements as I see, for example

Comment: @Alexey Not really any benefits. If you inspect their buttons though, they are <input> elements on a form.

Comment: heey so I tried this too, but nothing appears, the js scripts are not running apparently ...

Comment: @Xibition So I added a JSFiddle example, just imagine that the 3 scriptFunc's are in their own files which are included at the end of the html document. 'Val' holds the text that is in the text box at the time the button is pressed, this is passed through to each script for use.

Comment: You can add more validation to only call scripts if 'Val' isn't empty or whatever, tailor it to your need.

Comment: so I get the value but still can't run the scripts... i don't know why

Comment: @Xibition What do the scripts do? Can you create a JSFiddle with them all in the one JS box as separate functions?

Comment: heey I just found out what was the problem, jQuery is apparently not included at first so I had to add a script to execute the jQuery ! http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to load the scripts dynamically after you click on the button. This can be done via jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/application.css">
        <title>NFA2DFA</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <label>Enter value : </label><input type="text" maxlength="512" id="reg_expr"/>
      <div id="button" onclick="loadScripts();">OK</div>
        <div id="nfa"></div>
        <script>
            function loadScripts() {
                // Is the input empty?
                var value = $("#reg_expr").val();
                if (value.length != 0) {
                    // Loads and executes the scripts
                    console.log(value); // Displays the value of the input field
                    $.getScript("script1.js");
                    $.getScript("script2.js");
                    $.getScript("script3.js");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No way, man)) and what's next? You will advice to install node.js to run these scripts? It's too complicated an can be done much easier

Comment: my application is in nodejs, I have a question though, I don;t want it to work also if there is no input ... and i want to get the value of the input

Comment: @Alexey What are you talking about? Where do you see `node.js` here? See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron, it was a joke about node

Comment: I changed the code to check if the input field is empty and to get the value. Also done via jQuery.

Comment: I click on the button nothing happens, also nothing shows on the console neither...

Comment: PS : i am using Electron to build the App, does it accept jQuery ? it's like it doesnt execute any jQuery code

Comment: Do you view you HTML file just in the browser or do you use a web server? jQuery .getScript will not work if you just view it in your browser. It should work with Electron when you have installed it via npm. You can change the link of jquery in the header to the local jquery.js file.

Comment: Electron uses Chromium so it's like a web browser ? not sure

Comment: Yes it is a web browser and should work with jquery. I changed it in my code to use the cdn. I don't know if that works in Electron, so i suggest you to change it back to the /node_modules path (Like it was at the beginning).

Comment: thank youu found the solution here http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button tag instead of input tag. I suggest you to use onClick event like this:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="yourFunction()">Click me</button>
```

When the users click the button yourFunction() is call.

The result is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/application.css">
        <script src="script1.js"></script>
        <script src="script2.js"></script>
        <script src="script3.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
      <label>Enter value : </label><input type="text" maxlength="512" id="reg_expr"/>
      <button type="button" onclick="yourFunction()">Click me</button>

    </body>
</html>
```